# Bash. using cat does not include the first line while reading multiple lines till EOF

Tags: bash

currently I am using a while function, to store multiple user inputs, then print all of them on the same line. But the output is missing the first user input

Here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

while read input; do
  name=$(cat)
done
echo $name
```

This is the output:

```
dog 
cat
spear
cat spear
```

im not sure why "dog" is not being printed

Comment: The first line is consumed (so to speak) by `read input`, and put in the `input` variable; `cat` only sees the part after that. BTW, this is not a very good way to handle this; depending on what's in the file, storing it in a variable and using the variable without double-quotes can have weird effects.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want? It does what you seem to be after.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read input; do
  name="${name} $input"
done
echo $name
```

Comment: Thanks you! But another question is the `name="${name} $input"`. Does that store the `input` into an `name` array?

Comment: @Newcoder — There is no array in `name="${name} $input"`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is taboo, but this is my own preferred alternative to read/while loops.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cat >> print.ed << EOF
1p
q
EOF

cat >> pop.ed << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

next () {
[ -s stack ] && main
end
}

main () {
line=$(ed -s stack < print.ed)
echo "You now have ${line} as a variable to use as you wish."
ed -s stack < pop.ed
next
}

end () {
rm -v ./print.ed
rm -v ./pop.ed
rm -v stack
}

next
```

Comment: Sorry but where is `stack` ? defined? I don't follow, I'm an `ed` user my self, just being curious.

Comment: No problem.  "Stack" is just the name of whatever input text file you're using.  So if you wanted to rename a list of mp3 files for instance; I would run find and then pipe that into a stack file.

I call it a stack, because ed uses it like a stack in FORTH, which is where I learned this method.  Ed takes the first line off the top of the file, and that means I don't need a seperate counter; I just go by the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Right, I figured it out because of the `-s`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop:

```
$ name=$(cat)
dog
cat
spear
CONTROL-D

$ echo "${name}"
dog
cat
spear
```